# How to access the path parameter of AWS API Gateway?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created a basic GET url in API Gateway; with a path parameter called "name".

How can I access this name param? I don't see it in neither event or context.

Am I mistaken at the purpose of the parameter path?

Let me use my play app for example:

```
GET /api/v1/person                      @controllers.PersonController.list(limit: Int ?= 50, offset: Long ?= 0)
GET /api/v1/person/$id<[0-9]+>          @controllers.PersonController.getById(id: Long)
GET /api/v1/person/$id<[0-9]+>/email    @controllers.PersonController.getEmailByPersonId(id: Long)
```

Is this achievable using AWS API Gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs you should be able to do this with a mapping template: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Modifying their example("Example Request and Response" near the bottom) to fit your URI it would look like this

```
//Resource: /api/v1/person/{id}

//With input template(this is what your lambda will see in the event):
{
    "id" : "$input.params('id')"
    "person" : $input.json(‘$.person')
}

//POST /api/v1/person/{id}
{
    "person" : {
        "name": "bob"
    }
}
```